# Convert basic disk to dynamic

Tags: hard-drive, dynamic

I have a Windows server 2008 system with 2 x 40 GB SSD hard disks. On first disk I have the OS installed and the second disk is unallocated. I want to mirror the OS on second disk using software RAID. The operation of converting the basic disks to dynamic can be performed without data loss ? After that the OS will be bootable ?
Thanks and kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a basic to a dynamic disk without dataloss, but it will be slow. Normally your drive will be bootable afterwards. Just make a backup to be sure :)

Comment: Ok i'll make a backup and then try. I'll post the result here later. Thanks